# On GForge, can you add a tracker number to an svn commit after it has been made?

Tags: svn, gforge

My peers like to use gforge tracker numbers in their svn commits so each commit relevant to the issue appears on that issue's tracker page on gforge. Not everyone remembers to do this, including me. Can tracker item numbers be associated to commits after they have been made? Or can this only be done at the time of commit?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with GForge Next 22.1, you can associate a TI to a commit after the fact.  Follow these steps:

- Go to the Code menu item in your Project
- Click the Commits tab
- Click the specific Commit that you want to associate
- In the Commit tab, go to the Tracker Item Associations section (hint: if the commit diff is long, trying clicking the "Commit Diff" button to hide it)
- Use the "Add Association"box to search by keyword or ID, then select it from the search results.  You'll see a kanban-style card show up to confirm it's associated.
- Now you can go back to the Tracker Item and see the commit there.

If you're on GForge SaaS, this feature has been available since July of this year.  If you're using GForge Next on-premise, you'll need version 22.1, which was released in early September.

Some other things you might want to know:

- You can configure commit rules for each project (repository), to require a valid Tracker Item ID or reject the commit.  This can prevent the situation you're describing from happening.  Check the SCM Admin for your Project to see all the options.
- You can also put the #12345 notation in the branch name, which will automatically associate all commits on that branch to the Tracker Item.